# How To Resume Atmosphere Connection When User Cancel Closing Browser Window

Tags: gwt, atmosphere

Our application is using atmosphere as the comet implementation,we want to implement the functionality that user can choose to stay within the site after browser window is closing by prompting the user "Are you sure" dialogbox .

To be specific, the problem originate from the fact that when user is trying to close browser window, when the confirm dialogbox is showing, the disconnect event is fired to atmosphere server no matter what user is going to choose.

We are using atmosphere for GWT, and we tried using the resumeOnBroadcast on resource option ,but with no luck.

And we also tried to intercept the closing event before it fired, also failed.

So can somebody help, thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `onClose(AtmosphereResponse)` request handler.

```
var socket = $.atmosphere;
var request = new $.atmosphere.AtmosphereRequest();

request.onClose(response){
    //handle the close here
}
var subSocket = socket.subscribe(request);
subSocket.push(data);
```

This is documented [here](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-API). This is on the client side.

Comment: Well that may works for jquery implementation ,but for our case GWT is used ,and perhaps there is no equivalent counterpart.